# asp.net: upload images to SQL using imageupload

Tags: asp.net, sql, file-upload

i have a database column 'images' which can hold binary data, for some reason the images doesnt want to upload. it doest pull any exceptions or aything wrong with the code:

here is extracts of the code

```
protected void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     string imgpath = FileUploadImage.FileName.ToString();
     DBConnectivity.Add(imgpath);
    }
here is the DBCoectivity Class:
public static void Add(string imgpath)
    {
        byte[] imgbt = null;
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(imgpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
         BinaryReader BR = new BinaryReader(fstream);
         imgbt = BR.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);

        SqlConnection myConnection = GetConnection();
        string myQuery = "INSERT INTO images( imagePath) VALUES ( @IMG )";
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(myQuery, myConnection);
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IMG",imgbt)); 
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in DBHandler", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet works for me:

```
byte[] imgbt = null;

if (FileUploadImage.HasFile)
{
    Stream photoStream = FileUploadImage.PostedFile.InputStream;
    imgbt = new byte[FileUploadImage.PostedFile.ContentLength];
    photoStream.Read(imgbt, 0, FileUploadImage.PostedFile.ContentLength);
}
```

Also, you were inserting the image name (misspelled as parameter to Add method and bad choice of variable name as it is not a path) into the database, not the binary data. It should read:

```
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO images(imgbt) VALUES (@IMG)";
```

Here's a sample tutorial which explains it better:

[File Upload with ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1757/File-Upload-with-ASP-NET)

Comment: Updating answer with tutorial link.